# Finding solutions to a single linear equation in n variables, or determine that no solution exists

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, language-agnostic

Suppose you have a linear equation in n variables. The goal is to either determine that no  **integer** solution is possible, or determine the smallest coefficient vector, **for an integer solution**.

In other words, let `ax=b` where `x` is the vector you want to find, and `a` is a vector of coefficients. `b` is a scalar constant. Find `x` such that the sum of `x1, ... ,xn` is minimized, and all `xi`s are integers. Or, determine that no such `x` exists. From now on, I will say that `|x|` is the sum of the `xi`'s.

What is an efficient way to solve this? I feel like this is similar to the Knapsack problem, but I'm not entirely sure.

**My Solution**

The way I tried to solve this was doing a Breadth-First Search on the space of vectors, where the *breadth* would be the sum of the vector entries.

At first I did this naively, starting from `|x| = 0`, but when `n` is even moderately large, and the solution is non-trivial, the number of vectors generated is enormous (`n ^ |x|` for each `|x|` you go through). Even worse, I was generating many duplicates. Even when I found a way to generate almost no duplicates, this way is too slow.

Next, I tried starting from a higher `|x|` from the beginning, by putting a lower bound on the optimal `|x|`. I sorted `a` to have it in decreasing order, then removed all `ai > b`. Then a lower bound on `|x|` is `b / a[0]`. However, from this point, I had difficulty quickly generating all the vectors of size `|x|`. From here, my code is mostly hacky.

In the code, `b = distance`, `x = clubs`, `n = numClubs`

Here is what it looks like:

```
short getNumStrokes (unsigned short distance, unsigned short numClubs, vector<unsigned short> clubs) {
    if (distance == 0)
        return 0;

    numClubs = pruneClubs(distance, &clubs, numClubs);
    //printClubs (clubs, numClubs);

    valarray<unsigned short> a(numClubs), b(numClubs);
    queue<valarray<unsigned short> > Q; 

    unsigned short floor = distance / clubs[0];

    if (numClubs > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numClubs; i++) {
            a[i] = floor / numClubs;
        }

        Q.push (a);
    }

    // starter vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < numClubs; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numClubs; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                a[j] = distance / clubs[0];
            else
                a[j] = 0;
        }

        if (dot_product (a, clubs) == distance)
            return count_strokes(a);

        // add N starter values
        Q.push (a);
    }

    bool sawZero = false;

    while (! Q.empty ()) {
        a = Q.front(); // take first element from Q
        Q.pop(); // apparently need to do this in 2 operations >_<

        sawZero = false;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numClubs; i++) {
            // only add numbers past right-most non-zero digit
            //if (sawZero || (a[i] != 0 && (i + 1 == numClubs || a[i + 1] == 0))) {
            //    sawZero = true;

                b = a; // deep copy
                b[i] += 1;

                if (dot_product (b, clubs) == distance) {
                    return count_strokes(b);
                } else if (dot_product (b, clubs) < distance) {
                    //printValArray (b, clubs, numClubs);
                    Q.push (b);
                }
            //}
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

EDIT: I'm using valarray because my compiler isn't C++ 11 compliant, so I can't use array. Other code suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Just use the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Don't think we covered that in Numerical Computing; can you explain like I'm 5?

Comment: I feel like I'm not getting your notation. What is the type of `b`? A scale or a vector? What is `ax`? Dot product, or something else?

Comment: Well, if you can tolerate minimizing the sum of squares, then what you're looking for is a [linear least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) solution, which the psuedoinverse provides.  It's not the best approach to obtaining the solution though, I suggest reading through that link...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about linear algebra.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves b is a scalar. ax is the dot product between a and x.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth But the problem is programming... as in I can't seem to program it. (it's an old computing contest problem)

Comment: Linear equations exist in linear spaces. Vectors made of natural numbers don't form a linear space.

Comment: Solve as you would with any linear system and then minimize using Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @us2012 I would solve by finding inverse of a matrix. However the matrix is not square for n > 1 and thus has no inverse.

Comment: @n.m. Is the OP trying to minimize over the natural numbers?

Comment: @n.m. Looking for an integer solution.

Comment: @BlackSheep: Ah, you should probably make that explicit in your question!

Comment: @BlackSheep Would be a good idea to mention that in the question...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Fixed by adding integer solution in every place I could find.

Comment: *"Bread-First Search"* - my daily morning routine.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming might be a good starting point.

Comment: @us2012 OK, cool. Are there any IP algos which are relatively simple to implement? The article only mentioned 1 simple one: Tabu search.

Comment: I believe you are looking for "linear Diophantine equations in N variables".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an equality constrained integer knapsack problem:

```
min |x|
s.t. ax = b
     x integer
```

If you have access, CPLEX or GUROBI can generally solve such problems quite easily.

Otherwise, consider some reductions of the constraint set

(e.g., http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2002/11/561.ps)

Comment: [glpk](http://www.gnu.org/s/glpk/), the GNU Linear Programming Kit, is a free solution.

Comment: @ Paul Rubel great point.  I think coin-or has some open source solutions as well